# Две одинаковые цифры

Tags: python, python-3.x

Определите, верно ли, что в заданном четырехзначном числе ровно две одинаковые цифры.

**Входные данные:**
На вход подается целое число k (1000≤k≤9999).

**Выходные данные:**
Выведите 1 при положительном ответе на вопрос задачи и любое другое целое число в противном случае.

**Примечание:**
Запрещается использовать if, for, while, abs, round.
Можно использовать массивы и функции.

Comment: Кстати говоря, дробные числа тоже нельзя использовать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Учись строить алгоритмы!

```
number = list(input()) 
print(int((len(set(number)) == 3)))
```

Comment: В вашем варианте 5555 даст единицу

Comment: Прошу прощения, опечатался. Вот верный вариант: 
```number = list(input())
print(int(not (len(number) == len(set(number)))))```

Comment: Странно, опять 5555 дает единицу

Comment: А он и должен выдавать единицу. В условии написано: если число имеет две или более одинаковых цифр, нужно вывести единицу или другое целое число.

Comment: четырехзначном числе **ровно две** одинаковые цифры.

Comment: Все-все-все! Вот окончательное решение: ```number = list(input())
print(int((len(set(number)) == 3)))```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 9998
print(len(str(a)) - len(set(str(a)))) # 2

a = 9908

print(len(str(a)) - len(set(str(a)))) # 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо большой, но я уже решил с помощью костылей :))))

```
def funс(a):
    return (a ** 2) ** (1/2)
k = int(input())
print((int(funс(k%10//1-k%100//10)/(funс(k%10//1-k%100//10)+1)+(1/2))+int(funс(k%10//1-k%1000//100)/(funс(k%10//1-k%1000//100)+1)+(1/2))+int(funс(k%10//1-k%10000//1000)/(funс(k%10//1-k%10000//1000)+1)+(1/2))+int(funс(k%100//10-k%1000//100)/(funс(k%100//10-k%1000//100)+1)+(1/2))+int(funс(k%100//10-k%10000//1000)/(funс(k%100//10-k%10000//1000)+1)+(1/2))+int(funс(k%1000//100-k%10000//1000)/(funс(k%1000//100-k%10000//1000)+1)+(1/2)))*((int(funс(k%10//1-k%100//10)/(funс(k%10//1-k%100//10)+1)+(1/2))+int(funс(k%10//1-k%1000//100)/(funс(k%10//1-k%1000//100)+1)+(1/2))+int(funс(k%10//1-k%10000//1000)/(funс(k%10//1-k%10000//1000)+1)+(1/2))+int(funс(k%100//10-k%1000//100)/(funс(k%100//10-k%1000//100)+1)+(1/2))+int(funс(k%100//10-k%10000//1000)/(funс(k%100//10-k%10000//1000)+1)+(1/2))+int(funс(k%1000//100-k%10000//1000)/(funс(k%1000//100-k%10000//1000)+1)+(1/2)))-3)*((int(funс(k%10//1-k%100//10)/(funс(k%10//1-k%100//10)+1)+(1/2))+int(funс(k%10//1-k%1000//100)/(funс(k%10//1-k%1000//100)+1)+(1/2))+int(funс(k%10//1-k%10000//1000)/(funс(k%10//1-k%10000//1000)+1)+(1/2))+int(funс(k%100//10-k%1000//100)/(funс(k%100//10-k%1000//100)+1)+(1/2))+int(funс(k%100//10-k%10000//1000)/(funс(k%100//10-k%10000//1000)+1)+(1/2))+int(funс(k%1000//100-k%10000//1000)/(funс(k%1000//100-k%10000//1000)+1)+(1/2)))-4) // 10)
```

Comment: Какой ужас......

Comment: Ййййепонский бох.... Только сейчас заценил длину решения ))

Comment: @entithat Я это добавил в избранное — не каждый день такое увидишь...